# How to get time difference between two date time in javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, datetime

I want time duration between two date time. I have the start date, start time, end date and end time. Now I have to find the difference between them.

Actually I have tried with this following code, but I got the alert like 'invalidate date'.

```
function myfunction()
{
    var start_dt = '2013-10-29 10:10:00';
    var end_dt = '2013-10-30 10:10:00';

    var new_st_dt=new Date(start_dt);
    var new_end_dt=new Date(end_dt);

    alert('new_st_dt:'+new_st_dt);
    alert('new_end_dt:'+new_end_dt);

    var duration=new_end_dt - new_st_dt;

    alert('duration:'+duration);
}
```

the alert msg like as follows:

```
new_st_dt:invalid date 
new_end_dt: invalid date
duration:NaN
```

when I run in android simulator I got these alert messages.

Please help me how to get it? How to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You're passing an invalid ISO date string to that `Date()` constructor. It needs a form like

```
YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss
```

for instance

```
2013-10-29T10:10:00
```

So you basically forgot the `T` to separate date and time. But even if the browser reads in the ISO string now, you would not have an unix timestamp to calculate with. You either can call

```
Date.parse( '2013-10-29T10:10:00' );  // returns a timestamp
```

or you need to explicitly parse the *Date object*, like

```
var duration=(+new_end_dt) - (+new_st_dt);
```

---

Further read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting you timestamps as isoformat so javascript recognizes them. (you put a "T" between the date and time). An example: `'2013-10-29T10:10:00'`

Answer (score 0):

```
 function dateDiff(){
var start_dt = '2013-10-29 10:10:00';
var end_dt = '2013-10-30 10:10:00';

var d1= start_dt ;
d1.split("-");
var d2= end_dt ;
d2.split("-");
var t1 = new Date(d2[0],d2[1],d2[2]);
var t2 = new Date(d1[0],d1[1],d1[2]);
var dif = t1.getTime() - t2.getTime();
var Seconds_from_T1_to_T2 = dif / 1000;
return Math.abs(Seconds_from_T1_to_T2);
}
```